# Can two sonarqube instances have same database server

Tags: database, performance, sonarqube, high-availability, multiple-instances

Is it possible to have two instances of sonarqube pointing  to same database server. So that both instances are pointing to same information(without data center edition)

Answer (score 1):

(Disclaimer : I'm working at SonarSource)
You should not do that without DCE, this may break your database.

Cheers